# Is there any train from Germany to France where I can bring my car with me?

Tags: trains, germany, france

I drive often, from Saxony, Germany to South of France, Bordeaux region. In the past there was an option to put your car in a train and drive to Paris and from there, drive further, either by train or by yourself. However now I wasn't able to find it anymore.

Comment: The DB stopped those trains, I guess you know that.

Comment: @o.m. There are still car-trains in Germany, now operated by other companies than DB. According to Wikipedia, there are also still car trains in France. I am not sure though, if there are any reasonable or helpful connections from Saxony to Bordeaux.

Comment: one to paris would help me already, to sleep the first part of the travel and then do the rest alone - however to enter/leave Paris with car isn't really something that I would love to do

Comment: Just leave early enough and Paris traffic should be fine.

Comment: @JonathanReez that's more related with "when" the train arrives in Paris, then the when I want to live.

Answer (score 5):

The auto train from Paris to Bordeaux is no longer listed in the [**2018** SNCF brochure](http://medias.sncf.com/sncfcom/pdf/autotrain/Brochure_AUTO-TRAIN_FR.pdf). (Map on page 3. The current [English version](http://medias.sncf.com/sncfcom/pdf/autotrain/Brochure_AUTO-TRAIN_FR.pdf) is from 2017.)

[SNCF recommends](http://medias.sncf.com/sncfcom/pdf/autotrain/Brochure_AUTO-TRAIN_FR.pdf) their partner [Expedicar](https://expedicar.com/). They collect your car and drive it to your destination, either on a truck, or with a driver. Unfortunately, they are not as fast as the train used to be.

For example, for Strasbourg to Bordeaux, prices currently are:

- 85 Eur (some kind of car rental system, depends on driver availability)
- 419 Eur (truck, 9 days)
- 820 Eur (professional driver, 3 days).

There are also international options, google for [Autotransport](https://www.google.de/search?q=autotransport) or [Fahrzeugtransport](https://www.google.de/search?q=fahrzeugtransport). [UShip](https://www.uship.com) (an auction platform) quotes 563 Euro as a typical price for a VW Passat from Dresden to Bordeaux.

On the German side, there are only a few remaining trains in N-S/NW-SE direction. [Autoreisezug-Planer](https://www.autoreisezug-planer.de/uebersichtskarte.htm) has a map (red/orange stations are in use, white ones are closed), and more details in German (menu on the right).

Answer (score 1):

According to the helpful map on the Seat 61 website https://www.seat61.com/Motorail.htm there are southbound motorail services still from Paris including one to Bordeaux and also services southbound from Düsseldorf but those only go to Italy or Austria so you are out of luck.

Comment: if the TGV isn't striking :P but for me the main part would be to avoid the bad german motorails and part of the expensive french one..